# Why does compiling a kernel module with `SUBDIRS=...` fail on newer kernels?

Tags: kernel, kernel-modules

I am compiling a kernel module with a build script including the following command:

```
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build SUBDIRS=$PWD modules
```

This used to work... but now it fails with this error:

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-42-generic'
fs/aufs/Makefile:3: fs/aufs/magic.mk: No such file or directory
make[3]: *** No rule to make target 'fs/aufs/magic.mk'.  Stop.
scripts/Makefile.clean:67: recipe for target 'fs/aufs' failed
make[2]: *** [fs/aufs] Error 2
Makefile:1738: recipe for target '_clean_fs' failed
make[1]: *** [_clean_fs] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-42-generic'
Makefile:39: recipe for target 'clean' failed
make: *** [clean] Error 2
```

The build stops there with no other output. What happened?

Comment: So, in your current directory, is there a file `fs/aufs/magic.mk` ?

Comment: No, it doesn't exist. This error is being printed by a makefile within the kernel, so it would be under the kernel source tree, not $PWD. It doesn't exist with older kernels, either. I finally figured out what is going on (see answer): in newer versions, the SUBDIRS argument is totally ignored, so it's trying to compile the whole kernel (or a lot of it, anyway). But no configuration has been done so it fails right away.

Answer (score 3):

The vital clue is in the kernel version that failed to compile: 5.4.0-42-generic.

Support for the `SUBDIRS` parameter was [removed in that version](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=7e35b42591c058b91282f95ce3b2cf0c05ffe93d) in favor of the newer `M` parameter and `KBUILD_EXTMOD` environment variable.

Previous versions (since [11/2018](https://patchwork.kernel.org/project/linux-kbuild/patch/1542726258-8418-1-git-send-email-yamada.masahiro@socionext.com/)) printed a warning even while successfully compiling, so depending on how often you update your packages, this should've been showing up for a while:

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.3.0-40-generic'
Makefile:227: ================= WARNING ================
Makefile:228: 'SUBDIRS' will be removed after Linux 5.3
Makefile:229:
Makefile:230: If you are building an individual subdirectory
Makefile:231: in the kernel tree, you can do like this:
Makefile:232: $ make path/to/dir/you/want/to/build/
Makefile:233: (Do not forget the trailing slash)
Makefile:234:
Makefile:235: If you are building an external module,
Makefile:236: Please use 'M=' or 'KBUILD_EXTMOD' instead
Makefile:237: ==========================================
```

Don't ignore these warnings! They nearly always indicate areas of [technical debt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_debt).

You need to update your build to use the [new way to build external modules](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/kbuild/modules.html).