# objtool won't build on RHEL 9.1, I'm getting make warnings and objtool compile error, Why?

Tags: rhel

I'm having the same issue with RHEL 9.1. Does anyone know what might be causing this?

I try to run a make and continue to get the following error:

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/kernels/5.14.0-162.12.1.el9_1.x86_64'
scripts/Makefile.build:481: warning: overriding recipe for target 'modules.order'
Makefile:1506: warning: ignoring old recipe for target 'modules.order'
  DESCEND objtool
make[3]: *** [Makefile:55: /usr/src/kernels/5.14.0-162.12.1.el9_1.x86_64/tools/objtool/objtool-in.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [Makefile:69: objtool] Error 2
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1412: tools/objtool] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/kernels/5.14.0-162.12.1.el9_1.x86_64'
make: *** [Makefile:24: all] Error 2
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: I see the same error with RHEL9.2 and 5.14.0-284.11.1.el9_2.x86_64.

Comment: Output of `make V=1`: ```make LDFLAGS= MAKEFLAGS=" " O=/usr/src/kernels/5.14.0-284.11.1.el9_2.x86_64 subdir=tools -C ./tools/ objtool
...make -C /usr/src/kernels/5.14.0-284.11.1.el9_2.x86_64/tools/build CFLAGS= LDFLAGS= /usr/src/kernels/5.14.0-284.11.1.el9_2.x86_64/tools/objtool/fixdep
make -f /usr/src/kernels/5.14.0-284.11.1.el9_2.x86_64/tools/build/Makefile.build dir=. obj=fixdep
make[3]: *** [Makefile:53: /usr/src/kernels/5.14.0-284.11.1.el9_2.x86_64/tools/objtool/objtool-in.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [Makefile:69: objtool] Error 2```

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution in [Why does compiling a kernel module with `SUBDIRS=...` fail on newer kernels?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/616539/why-does-compiling-a-kernel-module-with-subdirs-fail-on-newer-kernels) :

With previous kernel versions, I had used  `make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build SUBDIRS=/my/src/dir modules` to build a module.

With newer kernels it must be M instead of SUBDIRS,
`make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=/my/src/dir modules`.

See also https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/html/managing_monitoring_and_updating_the_kernel/managing-kernel-modules_managing-monitoring-and-updating-the-kernel#proc_compiling-custom-kernel-modules_managing-kernel-modules