# What is causing objtool Error 1 and 2 when compiling the kernel on Rocky Linux 9.1?

Tags: linux-kernel

The same question but without a solution (I could not comment): [objtool won't build on RHEL 9.1, I'm getting make warnings and objtool compile error, Why?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/736400/objtool-wont-build-on-rhel-9-1-im-getting-make-warnings-and-objtool-compile-e)

I hope pastebin is the way to post this. The result from "make V=1": https://pastebin.com/6rcLUQjX

Here are the last few lines:

> make LDFLAGS= MAKEFLAGS=" " O=/usr/src/kernels/5.14.0-162.23.1.el9_1.x86_64 subdir=tools -C ./tools/ objtool
> mkdir -p /usr/src/kernels/5.14.0-162.23.1.el9_1.x86_64/tools/objtool && make O=/usr/src/kernels/5.14.0-162.23.1.el9_1.x86_64 subdir=tools/objtool --no-print-directory -C objtool
> make -C /usr/src/kernels/5.14.0-162.23.1.el9_1.x86_64/tools/build CFLAGS= LDFLAGS= /usr/src/kernels/5.14.0-162.23.1.el9_1.x86_64/tools/objtool/fixdep
> make -f /usr/src/kernels/5.14.0-162.23.1.el9_1.x86_64/tools/build/Makefile.build dir=. obj=fixdep
> make -C /usr/src/kernels/5.14.0-162.23.1.el9_1.x86_64/tools/lib/subcmd/ OUTPUT=/usr/src/kernels/5.14.0-162.23.1.el9_1.x86_64/tools/objtool/
> make -C /usr/src/kernels/5.14.0-162.23.1.el9_1.x86_64/tools/build CFLAGS= LDFLAGS= /usr/src/kernels/5.14.0-162.23.1.el9_1.x86_64/tools/objtool/fixdep
> make -f /usr/src/kernels/5.14.0-162.23.1.el9_1.x86_64/tools/build/Makefile.build dir=. obj=fixdep
> make[2]: *** [Makefile:55: /usr/src/kernels/5.14.0-162.23.1.el9_1.x86_64/tools/objtool/objtool-in.o] Error 1
> make[1]: *** [Makefile:69: objtool] Error 2
> make: *** [Makefile:1412: tools/objtool] Error 2

I have tried:

> make clean; make; yum -y update; dnf download --source kernel; yum install kernel-devel-$(uname -r); yum install kernel-headers-$(uname -r)